# "Drop Table if exists" doesn't allow me to alter a temp table in the script after it's run once

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In a script, I have a temp table. In my script, I'm using this block to create the table

```
drop table if exists #myTempTable 

create #myTempTable (
  dataid INT
, Description NVARCHAR(100) 
)

insert into #myTempTable 
(1 , 'blah')
```

I can insert data into it just fine. I can run it multiple times. But if I want to change the columns in the table *after I've run this once*, I can't just add or remove the column in the script's "Create" definition and "insert" statement. I have to run `Drop Table if exists #myTempTable` independently first, or I will get the error:

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Is this expected? I can't find any documentation on this 'feature'. It seems I should be able to drop the table within the script the same as I run it independently.

Comment: Because its in the same context the structure is cached (or something). If you put a go inbetween I think it works. BTW tables have columns not fields.

Comment: When the table doesn't exist at all at batch compilation time then compilation of statements referencing it are deferred until statement execution time. If the table already exists at batch compilation time you get no deferred compilation and all statements referencing it need to be consistent with that structure

Comment: Assuming you are running the script in an SSMS query window, just Add a `GO` batch terminator after the drop.

Comment: Alternatively, do the sensible thing and put the `drop` at the *end* of the batch also

Comment: Why would a temporary table exist and have to be dropped? `#myTempTable` is only visible to the connection that created it. The only way you'd need to drop it is if you executed the same script multiple times using the same connection. When the connection closes, the temp table will be dropped automatically

Comment: @DaleK  GO works. Thank you. I use these in small parts of large code. I often just want to run a section of the code, see how it works, then make changes. So resetting everything there is helpful, rather than dropping at the end of a long script.  
BTW, updated my language. Thanks for the nudge.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The drop isn't particularly for the final product. This is to help during the development and testing. So yes, I use the same script multiple times using the same connection. If I don't drop it, it will complain that it already exists when the script hits the 'Create' part.

Comment: Then drop the table at the end of the script. Trying to drop something that shouldn't be there like this is a bug